# how to build sql server 2008 datetime object and insert it using perl DBI

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

How can i build a sql server 2008 datetime object with perl and insert it using the dbi module to specific  table could someone provide example

Answer (score 2):

If using ODBC:

`my $sth = $dbh->do(q/insert into mytable (mydatetimecol) values(?)/;
$sth->execute(q/{ts 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'}/);`

The datetime can also have '.mmm' on the end for milliseconds.

If not using ODBC it will depend on what DBD you are using.

Comment: bohica: can you explain a little bit more what you've done? For example, where is the Perl variable containing the original time, and what format (or representation) is it in? And how do you convert back, from a MSSQLServer query result, into a Perl variable? Many thanks - TIA

Comment: There is no perl variable containing the time. The time was yyyy-mm... etc and I meant for that to be replaced with a valid date time e.g., 2013-04-20 10:12:12. If you want to put the datetime into a perl variable do that and change the q/ to qq/.