# how to pass datetime format using perl script to sql server?

Tags: sql-server, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

      use DBI;
      use Data::Dumper;
      use strict;


       my $DSN = q/dbi:ODBC:SQLSERVER/;
       my $uid = q/username/;
       my $pwd = q/password/;

       my $first_param=723454;
       my $current_date="2012-10-25 00:30:21";
       my $after_2min="2012-10-25 05:47:41";


       my $dbh = DBI->connect($DSN,$uid,$pwd) or die "Coudn't Connect SQL"; 

       my $sql2 = "insert reverise_call_main_menu call_number,call_originate_time,call_inbetween_time,call_after_2min_time) values(?,?,?,?)";
       my $sth2 = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
       $sth2->execute($first_param,$current_date,'null',$after_2min);

       $sth2->finish;
       $dbh->disconnect;
```

whenever i execute a program i got following error:

output:-

DBD::ODBC::st execute failed: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string. (SQL-22007)

Comment: http://www.martin-evans.me.uk/node/54 doesn't look trivial though

Comment: It looks like you would have to provide some sort of coersion in order to get it into the database. There is a similar thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044445/how-to-build-sql-server-2008-datetime-object-and-insert-it-using-perl-dbi

Comment: Been a long time since I coded in PERL...  Are you sure the error is with your datetime formats?  What about the 'null', shouldn't that be undef?  Also, your INSERT stmt looks like it's missing an open parenthesis after the table name.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that SQL Server does not like the format of your datetime strings.  You may wish to use [DateTime::Format::DBI](https://metacpan.org/module/CFAERBER/DateTime-Format-DBI-0.040/lib/DateTime/Format/DBI.pm) to help get the formatting right.